# Not able to invoke function of a controller in Jasmine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, controller, jasmine

```
'use strict';
define([], function () {

function myController($scope) {
    //Do something...
    };
}

myController.inject = ['$scope'];

return myController;
```

});

For the above controller, I am not able to call myController. Pls see code below(jasmine).

```
describe('myController', function() {
'use strict';

var controller, scope;

beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {
    controller = $controller;
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
}));

describe('sum', function () {
    it('1 + 1 should equal 2', function () {
        expect(scope.listingsBarController()).toBe(2);
    }); 
});
});
```

It says that undefined is not a function(while evaluating scope.listingsBarController.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't inject controller. Your need to inject controller slightly differently.  Do as below in before Each.

```
controller= $controller('myController', {$scope: scope});
```